# jQuery .html() is returning as 'undefined'

Tags: jquery

For some reason when I use `html()` it returns as undefined. Using `text()` doesn't work either.

I've searched through the internet as well as stackoverflow, and all of the answers have not solved my problem. I'm a novice a jQuery, so please be easy on me :)

Here's my code:

jQuery:

```
$("#cartBtn").on("click", function() {
    var total = $("#cart_cost").html();
    $("#total").append(total);
});
```

HTML:

```
<td id="cart_cost" class="text-right">$10</td>

<a id="total">Total: </a>
```

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4q7qha5r/1/

Comment: Please post a complete sample where you can reproduce the problem, contain the `cartBtn`  and the parent of your `td` element.

Comment: You sure it's not $("#cart_cost") that returns undefined, rather than .html()? try `console.log($("#cart_cost"));`

Comment: @Tapirboy A `$( ... )` will never return `undefined`. It will always return a jQuery result set. But the result set might be empty. `$( ... ).length === 0`

Comment: @t.niese Ah, yes you are right, and calling .html() on an empty result set  would give ´null´ rather than ´undefined´.  Makes you wonder if jQuery is loaded correctly. But then again the click event seems to fire..

Comment: @Tapirboy Yes it actually should return `null`, but I would guess it is copy&past coding anyway. But the problem that `<td>`  is unwrapped if there is no ascendant `<table>` is still an interesting case.

Answer (score 1):

problem In Your html Codes

```
 td Work Inside in table
```

if **td** has Not Is Parent table td Not Parse By jQuery

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        var total = $("#cart_cost").html();
        alert(total);
        $("#total").append(total);
    });
```

Simply Add Table Tag Outer Of td Tag

```
 <table>
    <td id="cart_cost" class="text-right">$10</td>
    <a id="total">Total: </a>
    </table>
```

Comment: I don't really see how this answers the question. Could you please provide more of an explanation?

Comment: While it might be the problem, the code you provide is invalid html, neither `a` nor `td`  are a valid child of `table`.

Comment: Sorry Friends i Am New In Stack OverFlow And I Dont Speak Good English So Sorry For Missing Explanation :)

Comment: @facebook-100000384953184 - It's OK - we can see that you are trying hard :) Please take a look at the comments users have left for you, there are some problems with your answer.

Comment: `[...]if td has Not Is Parent table td Not Parse By jQuery[...]` jQuery is _just_ a DOM traversing and manipulation library.  If `td`  is not a _descendant_ of a `table` tag, then the content of `td` is _unwrapped_  **by the browser**. If there is an _ascending_ `table` element and the `td` is not a child of `tr` then the `td` will be _assigned_ to the closest `table`, and possible missing elements like `tbody` and `tr`  will be create **by the browser**. So if your assumption is really true, then the `td` does not exist in the DOM, and thats why jQuery can't find it.

Comment: Woops, I should've included more code. I actually do have it wrapped in a <table> tag, my bad.

Comment: Yes You need Wrap With Table It Done By me

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `.html()` can be undefined due to bad html when initializing jquery object

```js
var obj = $('<!-- sad --><div>hello</div>');
console.log(obj.html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```